# how to set Diffie Hellman key size to 2048 in OpenJDK

Tags: java, jsse

A security audit I just ran turned up that we are using a sub-par key strength (recommended 2048 or higher, ours is 1024 bits) for the Diffie-Hellman groups (TLS). Upon researching I found that starting JDK 8 we can set the DH key size to be 2048. 
All the options suggested in [How to expand DH key size to 2048 in java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502672/how-to-expand-dh-key-size-to-2048-in-java-8)
apply to Oracle JDK and they do work for that.

However, when I try to set `-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048` as JVM argument on my Ubuntu with OpenJDK 8 it is still remaining to be 1024 bits. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can, see http://serverfault.com/a/722254/216617 Can you switch to [Oracle JDK](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java)?

Comment: The comment you mentioned talks about glassfish which jdk 7. I am on OpenJDK 8 which is theotrically inline with Oracle JDK 8. Am I missing something? I would hate to switch to Oracle JDK just for this one thing

Comment: OpenJDK 8 should definitely support `jdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize`. Here's the [change that added that support to OpenJDK 8](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/rev/0d5f4f1782e8). Can you provide more details? What version of OpenJDK 8 are you using? How are you verifying the key size? What happens if you set the key size to, say, 65500 instead of 2048?

Comment: java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_72-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_72-internal-b05)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.72-b05, mixed mode)

I added -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 as JVM arg.

When I run the security audit reports on the OpenJDK instance it says, I am still using 1024 bits. 
Whereas on the Oracle JDK 1.8.0.72 instance, the key size violation is being handled after adding jvm arg.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an issue on latest JDK versions, I have verified on `JDK 9.0.4` and `JDK 10`. As stated in the comments of the [bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8198542) : The `jdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize` property only has impact on the Server side handshaker code and as such, should be used on server side JVM.

In the latest Oracle `JDK 8u161`, this works if this option is set in server side. From `JDK 9` onwards, the FFDHE is available and the property has an effect when set in client side.